# 'Driver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, attributeerror

Could someone please have a look into the scripts I share below and let me know what may I be missing?

The error is in this part of the script:

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.view_all_link).click()

where I believe the driver is unable to locate the 'View All' link, after clicking on the dropdown menu
item 'Data' (refer the image below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9cSf.png)

Main Class:

```
   import unittest
    from pageobjects.form_case_exports import FormCaseExports
    from pageobjects.login import Login
    from webdriver import Driver
    from values import inputs
    import time
    
    
    class TestCCHQ(unittest.TestCase):
    
        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = Driver()
            self.driver.navigate(inputs.base_url)
            login_page = Login(self.driver)
            login_page.accept_cookies()
            login_page.enter_username(inputs.login_username)
            login_page.enter_password(inputs.login_password)
            login_page.click_submit()
    
        def test_form_case_exports(self):
            form_case_exports = FormCaseExports(self.driver)
            try:
                form_case_exports.click_data_dropdown()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                print("Data Menu Visible and Click-able")
                time.sleep(2)
         
    
        def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.instance.quit()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

form_case_exports class:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from values import inputs

class FormCaseExports:

    def __init__(self, driver):  # initialize each WebElement here
        self.driver = driver
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10)
        self.data_dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ProjectDataTab"]'))) # Data dropdown
        self.view_all_link = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/nav/ul/li[3]/ul/li[6]/a"
            #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'View All')))  # View All link



    def click_data_dropdown(self):
        self.data_dropdown.click()
        print("Data dropdown clicked")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.view_all_link).click()
        print("View All link clicked")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Result:

Cookies accepted

Login Successful

Data dropdown clicked

### 'Driver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
Data Menu Visible and Click-able
.

Ran 1 test in 21.552s

Let me know if the HTML content will be required to figure out the issue

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can put time.sleep(2) in between to check if it is loading later in init method. or
don't include in init method

Answer (score 0):

Please the add the Visible wait and then clickable wait for "View All" link after click on data_dropdown click.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses, guys!

I ultimately moved the initialization of the locator for View_All out of init method - and this worked pretty well!

The other suggested methods sound good too - will try them out as well at some point in time :)